# Xcode project management: adding a iPad (Storyboards,iOS 5) to a iPhone project compatible with iOS 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, workspace

I have a mature iPhone project which needs to stay compatible with iOS 4. I would like to add 
an iPad version that uses Storyboards.
Whats the best pratice to organize such a project? I don't think it's possible to do this as an Universal project, because of the different iOS versions.

Of course I could just generate a second project for the iPad version, but then I would have to sync the changes manually between the versions.

Would it be a good idea to solve this with a Xcode workspace? If I got it right, it's possible to have several projects in a workspace.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd do is create one workspace with three targets: two apps and one library. Then you put the shared code in the library target that you include in both app targets.